Using random_password generation accross services for terraform
I would like to generate one password for the RDS database.

it will be stored in secrets manager
the password will be used by ECS to access the RDS

My code:
modules/secrets-manager.tf

resource "random_id" "prefix" {
  byte_length = 4
}
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%^"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "rds_password" {
  kms_key_id              =  aws_kms_key.database.key_id
  name                    = "rds_admin_password-dev"
  description             = "RDS Admin password"
  recovery_window_in_days = 0
  force_overwrite_replica_secret = true
}
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.rds_password.id
  secret_string = random_password.password.result
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "rds" {
  name = aws_secretsmanager_secret.rds_password.name
  depends_on = [
    aws_secretsmanager_secret.rds_password
  ]
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.rds.id
}


Outputs.tf
output "rds_admin_password" {
  description = "The RDS admin password"
  value       = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret.secret_string
  sensitive   = true
}

I refer to the password in different module as follows:
password = module.security.rds_admin_password

This generates different passwords instead of using the same password.
How to prevent that and use the same password?
Error Message

Error: creating Secrets Manager Secret (rds_admin_password-testingenv-dev): operation error Secrets Manager: CreateSecret, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: XXXXXXX, ResourceExistsException: The operation failed because the secret rds_admin_password-testingenv-dev already exists.

For each test run, I create a new secret manager name.
It wants to create 3 secrets instead of one. This is why I run into this error.
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Is the output in the same module as where the secret is created? Also, can you add the module call for creating RDS to the question?

I was not able to reproduce your issue. BTW random_id doesn't seem to be used?
When running the following code the password doesn't change:
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%^"
}

output "password" {
  value     = random_password.password.result
  sensitive = true
}

Anyway, try using the keepers property of random_id and/or random_password - it's an arbitrary map of values that, when changed, will trigger recreation of resource.
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length           = 16
  special          = true
  override_special = "_!%^"

  keepers = {
    # change the value to trigger a new password
    version = "v1"
  }
}

output "password" {
  value     = random_password.password.result
  sensitive = true
}

Testing the code:
terraform init
terraform apply -auto-approve
terraform output -raw password


thanks for your advice! I wasn't aware of this  functionality

I used random-id for an earlier version for secrets manager

@user23663430 no problem :-) If my answer helped solving your issue please consider upvoting it and/or mark it as the correct answer.

unfortunately, it hasn't solved my issue. but thanks for  explaining the functionality

@user23663430 try changing the output variable value to random_password.password.result

instead of using Secrets Manager?

just tried to run it - the same error persists. what a mistery... . I updated the error message in the post.

Since 2022, Amazon RDS supports integration with AWS Secrets Manager. you can use the following terraform code to create your RDS with random password. the password will then be pushed on secret manager.
resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage           = 10
  db_name                     = "mydb"
  engine                      = "mysql"
  engine_version              = "8.0"
  instance_class              = "db.t3.micro"
  manage_master_user_password = true
  username                    = "foo"
  parameter_group_name        = "default.mysql8.0"
}

The advantage of this approach is the password is not stored in the terraform state which can be very interresting from security perspective.
You can then use data resource to get the secret from secret manager
References:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#managed-master-passwords-via-secrets-manager-default-kms-key

